# MSA 2040 SAN - duplicate virtual volume

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, storage, hp-modular-smart-array, hpe

Good Afternoon guys,

I have a MSA 2040 SAN for storage. My problem is that when I create a virtual volume and map it to a server, the server shows 2 volumes on the disk management. I've tried, many times, to delete the virtual volume and re-map it to the server but it is always the same.

Does anyone have experience with this storage model and with the knowledge to fix this problem?

Thank you!
[Screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7H0X.png)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have two paths to the MSA (either dual controller, or dual connections to a single controller).

As such, you should install and enable the Windows MPIO feature to properly account for both paths. You may need to run an mpclaim against the volume in order for the volume to be properly utilized.

Take a read through the [MSA best practices guide](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA4-6892ENW.pdf). Multipath portion starts at page 28 in the current version of the guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a MultiPath issue on the server client. i was abble to fix the problem with your help and the documentation that you send me.